# How can I use CSS in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, stylesheet

Can I use **CSS** for styling my **ReactNative** component. Currently I can only  use **StyleSheet** like this:

```
var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
 autocomplete: {
   backgroundColor: '#FFF',
   zIndex: 5,
 },
 ...
```

I want to use CSS instead of this as in **ReactJs**

Comment: Go through the documentation for more info http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/style.html#style

Comment: Fix link above: https://reactnative.dev/docs/style

Answer (score 5):

First create a file named `App.module.css`

then write your pure css here

```css
.container {
  background-color: rgb(44, 0, 95);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

then,

import the file in your js file

```
import style from './App.module.css';
```

Now you can this style like normal react native styling

```
<View style={style.container}>
```

Comment: Great approach! But when I do this I get the following error:

    `"None of these files exist:
  * components/App.module.css(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)"`

It looks like I can't import a file which ends in .css?

Comment: I get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean **pure css** ?

Have a look at [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components), the project is in active development.

This allow you to style your react components using css.

Comment: I mean just css.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once and I solved it using [this](https://github.com/sabeurthabti/react-native-css) component. I see is no longer under development however for me it was perfectly working.

What it does basically is taking your CSS files and it will generate from them some StyleSheet components that you can easily integrate in your react application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library:
[https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-css](http://atom-react-native-css)

You can style components with CSS and built in support for SASS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor:'#FFF',zIndex: 5}}></Text>
```