# React-Native styling using CSS stylesheets and class names

Tags: css, react-native, classname

I've just started working on a react-native app. The [official docs suggest](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html) to use JavaScript objects to create styles for your components, like so,

```
<Text style={style.text}>Blah Blah</Text>
const style = {
    text: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a className to the Text property, so I can add css using simple stylesheets. Is this even possible with react-native (I know we can do this in react, though)? Something like this,

```
<Text className="text-style"></Text>

// from CSS file
text-style: {
    font-size: 20;
}
```

Comment: no, it will not work as per my knowledge. You can check SO's document about styling for detailed info

Comment: No you can not use css classes in react native as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

The way React Native works with CSS styles is that the `StyleSheet` object is a js replica of CSS as a language. all you need to do is create a .js and import the js objects containing the `StyleSheet` objects.

an example of a StyleSheet JS object would be:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'; 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  otherStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

basically what it needs is an array of objects that follow the API of `StyleSheet`. A good rule of thumb is to write the css styles you know in camel case, e.g. `justifyContent` instead of `justify-content` the React Native engine does its best to replicate CSS through the use of these `StyleSheet` objects and reading documentation and examples will help you understand what `StyleSheet` is capable and not capable of(hint: `flex` and the `Dimensions` API are amazing and percentages are strings like `'50%'`).

Comment: It's not a replica of CSS -- you are passing JSON objects to StylesSheet.create, the API's are different, and browser spec is not present.

Answer (score 5):

There is no className in react-native but you can use a style object in react-native like this:

```
<Text style={textStyle}>Some Words</Text>

const textStyle = {
    fontSize: 20
}
```

Note: Some style properties are in different name. for example the css `font-size` is `fontSize` in react-native

Comment: `text-style` is incorrect syntax and won't work. You can't have a dash in a variable name like that.

Comment: Actually I'm working on a react-native app which uses Tailwind CSS and it has `className` all over the place (and they are effective). Not sure what is happening exactly. PS: Have a look: https://www.nativewind.dev/

Answer (score 1):

need to config react native sass /css transformer
https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer

Transform JSX className property to a style property that calculates styles at runtime in React Native. The plugin is used to match style objects containing parsed CSS media queries and CSS viewport units with React Native.

Please check out this link : https://github.com/kristerkari/babel-plugin-react-native-classname-to-dynamic-style

When using React native typescript, you need to install this package also
https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-types-for-css-modules

Answer (score 0):

The object that the documentation is referring to is the `StyleSheet` object in JSX. You need to import `StyleSheet` from `react-native`. The style that you have written to a `const` variable here will go into that object which you will create using `StyleSheet`.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    backgroundColor: '#0070af',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'#0070af'
  },
  textstyle:{
    color:'white',
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
  }});

export default styles;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import StyleSheet from react-native. Than create object with styles.

```js
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native"

const Home = () => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}></View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: blue,
    height: "100%",
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why anyone hasn't mentioned this but I think this is much better.

[How can I use CSS in ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949667/how-can-i-use-css-in-reactnative)

Make a file named App.moudle.css to write pure traditional css.
and import it like so-

```
import style from './App.module.css';

<View style={style.container}>
```

This would be much better as it would increase the shared code b/w react and react-native.

Much to my disappointment, there is yet to be a way to use css classes in react-native.